# Getting error working with ctypes, c_wchar_p.value

Tags: c, python-3.x, dll, ctypes

***SOLVED!***

i'm trying to use c dll found here (http://www.tripleheinz.com/index.php?page=1), in python.

I wrote the class you see below based on this dll, in the get_symbol method, i'm trying to read a string variable c_wchar_p, passed by reference to a dll function, this function should change the variable name to the name of the symbol of the loaded file, but when i try to print it with **symbol.value** i get **Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).**
If i use a c_wchar i can print symbol.value with no problems.

I attached at the end of the file the documentation of this dll, anyway it says that string in dll are Null terminated string in UTF-16LE encoding.

How can i properly read string in this dll?

Class:

```
from ctypes import *

class HccReader:

def __init__(self, rawpath):
    self.path = rawpath
    self.hcc = cdll.LoadLibrary("hcc.dll")

def open_file(self):
    self.handle = c_uint32()
    self.result = self.hcc.HCCOpenFile(self.path, byref(self.handle))

def load_hystory(self):
    self.length = c_uint32()
    self.result = self.hcc.HCCLoadHistory(self.handle, 1, 0, 0, byref(self.length))

def get_symbol(self):
    symbol = c_wchar_p()
    self.result = self.hcc.HCCGetSymbol(self.handle, pointer(symbol))
    print(symbol.value)
```

Class implementation:

```
from hccreader import HccReader as hcc

file = hcc("2018.hcc")
file.open_file()
file.load_hystory()
file.get_symbol()
```

download python files, dll, file to read, pdf form the author: https://www.mediafire.com/file/14y36rrwd1auoi2/hccread.zip

Comment: Please provide the C prototypes of the HCC functions you are wrapping.

Comment: @marktolonen, thanks for reply, i want to use every single function in the dll, attached in the first post you can find the documentation of dll api, otherwise providing myself C prototypes of every function properly formatted to be readed is pretty difficult. Anyway the function i'm having the most problems are: 1- HCCGetErrorMessage, reading the string passed by reference to the function tostore the message; 2- HCCGetSymbol,  reading the string passed by reference to the function tostore the Symbol; 3- Properly reading HCCRates struct double types, this struct is filled with func HCCGetRates

Comment: Questions should be self-contained.  See the [mcve] guidelines.  See `create_unicode_buffer` and `Structure` in the [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) for your specific problems, and update your question with a specific problem if you get stuck.

Comment: You're right, i did my best to explain my problem, english is not my native language tried my best really, i thiught my explanations was pretty self explanatory. Anyway thanks to your create_unicode_buffer i solved the string problem. Now i'm still having problem with structure but i can manage it somehow, that's why i didn't ask in the main pots.

Comment: Links are discouraged because they can change or go bad.  The questions and answers on this site need to be self-contained so they are valid for future users as well.  Plus don't require each reader to go out and download the source and docs when the relevant pieces should be included in the question.  If you've solved the question, you can answer your own question so the answer is provided for future readers as well.